# Fill color in bottle based upon textbox value in SVG image

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I want to fill the red color in the bottle based on the text box value user is entering.

```
<div style="float:left;">
  <label>Enter Value</label>
  <input min="0" max="100" value="50" id="fill-color" type="textbox" name="fillcolor" />%
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<svg id="octocat" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="450" viewBox="0 0 640 1280"><path id="face" d="M289.5 1c-24.5 1.5-44.8 5.2-47.7 8.8-1.5 1.8-1.5 21.6.1 29.7.8 4.1.6 5.5-.9 8.5-2.9 5.7-3.4 11.9-1.5 17.8 2 6 8.8 14.4 11 13.5.8-.3 1.5 0 1.5.6s-.5 1.1-1.2 1.1-.6.6.4 1.7c1.3 1.5 1.7 9.8 2.8 53.8l1.2 52-3.1 18c-7.8 45.2-19.6 83.7-48.4 158.5-11.8 30.7-19.7 53.4-19.7 56.2 0 .7 2.5-5.9 5.4-14.7 3-8.8 11-30.4 17.9-48 16.3-41.8 25.2-67.4 32.3-92.3 1.5-5.1 2.9-9 3.1-8.8 1.6 1.6-16.6 57.4-30.3 92.8-15.6 40.3-16.6 43.1-22.5 60.3-3.2 9.3-5.8 15.9-5.9 14.6 0-1.3-.3-2.1-.7-1.8-.3.4-.9 6.2-1.3 12.9-.6 10.2-1.2 13.4-3.5 18.8-13.7 32-26.5 140.3-22.7 192.1 1 13.7 4 31.1 5.4 31.7 1.5.7.8 4.8-1.2 6.5-1.8 1.5-2 2.9-2 14.4 0 18.6 3.2 44.5 12 98.3 8.2 49.7 11.4 75.5 14.9 117.5 3.7 43.9 4.4 58.5 3.8 83.5-.6 24.9-1.3 31.7-6.3 57.1-1.4 7.2-2.3 13.3-2.1 13.5.2.2 1.2-3.5 2.2-8.3 2.3-11.7 3.3-15.4 3.4-12.8.2 3.7-4.9 28.5-12.9 63-4.4 18.7-8.5 36.4-9.1 39.3-1.5 6.3-2.6 7.5-2.2 2.4.2-3.4.1-3.4-.8.8-1.5 6.9-.5 35.5 1.5 41l1.6 4.5-3.6-3.9-3.7-3.9.7 3.9c2 11.4 6.6 19 16.5 27.3 10.6 8.8 24.3 13.9 49.6 18.6 20.7 3.8 43.3 5.5 81.5 6.2 84.2 1.4 142.2-6.8 171.2-24.3 6.4-3.9 14.1-11.9 15.6-16.3.9-2.5.8-2.8-.8-2.4-1.7.5-1.7.2-.5-3.4.7-2.1 1.6-5.2 1.9-6.8l.7-3-3.5 3.4-3.5 3.3 1.6-4.3c1.1-3.1 1.6-8.6 1.6-18.9.1-14.8-2.1-34.8-3.3-30-.7 2.7-1.1 1.5-4.4-13-1.9-8.1-6.1-25.9-8.6-36.5-3-12.4-7-31.7-6.9-33.5 0-.8.9 1.4 1.9 5 2.6 9.3 2.4 6.3-.5-7.2-5-23.4-5.7-30.3-6.2-59.9-1-56.1 5.3-123.5 19.7-209.9 8.6-51.5 11.9-83.4 10.4-100-.4-4.7-.9-7.7-1.1-6.7-.6 2.2-2.3 1.2-2.3-1.4 0-1.1.4-1.7 1-1.4.6.4.9-1.1.7-3.9-.1-2.4.1-4.3.4-4 3.8 2.3 4.9-76.9 1.6-107.6-3.6-32.7-9-66.4-14.4-89.3-1.7-7.2-2.8-10.5-3.2-9.3-.5 1.3-1.6-.4-3.9-6.4-1.8-4.5-3.2-8.6-3.2-9.3 0-2.3 2 .9 4.4 7.3 1.4 3.6 2.5 5.8 2.5 5 0-.8-1.3-4.7-3-8.5-2.5-5.9-3.2-9.1-3.9-19.6-1.2-15.2-3.3-22.8-14.2-51.3-28.2-73.9-35.7-95.5-43.3-125.1-4.3-16.6-11.1-48.5-13.5-63.5-.7-4.1-1.6-8-2.1-8.6-1.7-2.1-3.1-36.2-2.7-66.3l.4-30.6 2.7-5c1.5-2.8 4.4-6.1 6.5-7.5 8-5.4 11.9-21.9 7.3-31.4-1.5-3.1-2.1-5.8-1.9-8.8l.4-4.3.8 5.3c1.5 9 2.8 4.4 3.4-11.6.5-14.2.4-15-1.6-17-2.5-2.5-6.9-3.8-19.8-5.7-21.9-3.2-69-4.3-99.9-2.5zm-47.2 61.1c2.5 3.6 2.6 3.7.6 4.2-1.6.4-1.8.3-.9-.8.7-.8.7-1.5.1-1.9-.5-.3-1.2 0-1.5.6-.3.7-.3.2 0-1.1.4-1.6.3-2.1-.5-1.7-.7.5-1.1-.1-1.1-1.5 0-1.2.1-2 .3-1.8.2.2 1.5 2 3 4zM405 72.3c0 .2-1 1.2-2.2 2.3l-2.3 1.9 1.9-2.3c1.8-2.1 2.6-2.7 2.6-1.9zM425.8 315c3.8 10.7 12.1 32.8 18.5 49 13.2 34 17.9 46.9 17.4 48.3-.2.6-1.1-1.2-2.1-3.9s-7.5-19.5-14.3-37.4c-15.5-40.2-27.3-73.1-27.3-75.9 0-1.5 1.5 2.4 7.8 19.9zM184 448.8c0 .4-1.7 5-3.9 10.2-2.1 5.2-4.4 11.9-5.1 14.7-.8 2.9-1.7 5.3-2.1 5.3-1 0 3.1-14.9 6.6-23.9 1.5-3.9 3.1-7.1 3.6-7.1s.9.4.9.8zm-17.3 69.4c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm317 5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-318 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm319 6.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm-320 2.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm311 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-302 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm312 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-322 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm10 6c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-314 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm305 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-315 1.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 2.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm316 2.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-9-.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-317 4c-.2 1.3-.4.5-.4-1.7-.1-2.2.1-3.2.4-2.3.2 1 .2 2.8 0 4zm327 4.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-318 1c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm309 .5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-319 7.5c-.2 1.6-.4.3-.4-2.7s.2-4.3.4-2.8c.2 1.6.2 4 0 5.5zm9 0c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm311 0c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 3c-.2 1.6-.4.5-.4-2.2 0-2.8.2-4 .4-2.8.2 1.3.2 3.5 0 5zM159 612.5l-.7 38-.1-27c-.2-22.8.6-50.2 1.3-49.3.1.2-.1 17.4-.5 38.3zm331.7-18.8c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-9-10c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-313 2.5c-.2 1.3-.4.5-.4-1.7-.1-2.2.1-3.2.4-2.3.2 1 .2 2.8 0 4zm314 12c-.2 1.8-.4.6-.4-2.7 0-3.3.2-4.8.4-3.3s.2 4.2 0 6zm-315 1.5c-.2 1.6-.4.3-.4-2.7s.2-4.3.4-2.8c.2 1.6.2 4 0 5.5zm324 29c-.1 4.9-.3.9-.3-8.7s.2-13.6.3-8.8c.2 4.9.2 12.7 0 17.5zm-325 7.5c-.1 4-.3.8-.3-7.2s.2-11.2.3-7.3c.2 4 .2 10.6 0 14.5zm324 16.5c-.2 2.1-.4.4-.4-3.7 0-4.1.2-5.8.4-3.8.2 2.1.2 5.5 0 7.5zm-331 4.5c-.2 1.3-.4.3-.4-2.2s.2-3.5.4-2.3c.2 1.3.2 3.3 0 4.5zm8 1.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm315 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm7 .5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-329 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm8 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-315.4 2.5c-.7.2-2.1.2-3 0-1-.3-.4-.5 1.2-.5 1.7 0 2.4.2 1.8.5zm311.4 16.5c-.2 1.3-.4.3-.4-2.2s.2-3.5.4-2.3c.2 1.3.2 3.3 0 4.5zm-305 0c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm316 17.5c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-328-8c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 3c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm311 12c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-319 8c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm8 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm318 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-8 5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-317 1.5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm8 1.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm316 4.5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-323 4c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm315 0c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-307 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm314 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-321 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-305 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm312 3c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-319 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm311 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm7 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-317 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm320 406.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm4.3 46.3c0 .5-1.9 3.3-4.2 6.1-12 14.6-42.4 24.4-94 30.5-17.9 2.1-103.1 3.1-126.7 1.4-19.7-1.3-36-3.3-49.5-6.1-10.2-2.1-29.1-7.7-28.4-8.5.3-.2 3 .5 6.2 1.6 27.2 9.3 81 14 145.1 12.5 43.2-.9 74.1-4.4 100.1-11 23.4-6 37-12.7 45.4-22.3 4.4-5 6-6.1 6-4.2z"/><path d="M159.1 681.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM178.6 1074.6c-.4 2-.5 3.8-.3 4 .3.3.8-1.1 1.1-3.2.4-2 .5-3.8.3-4-.3-.3-.8 1.1-1.1 3.2zM470.1 1074.6c-.2 1.8 3.2 16 3.5 14.9.2-.6-.5-4.4-1.5-8.5s-1.9-7-2-6.4zM177.1 1081.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM175.1 1089.6c-.7 3-1.1 5.7-.8 6 .2.2.9-2.1 1.6-5.2.7-3 1.1-5.7.8-6-.2-.2-.9 2.1-1.6 5.2zM474.1 1092c0 .8.8 4.6 1.8 8.5 1.1 3.8 1.9 6.3 2 5.5 0-.8-.8-4.7-1.8-8.5-1.1-3.9-1.9-6.3-2-5.5zM173.1 1098.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM171.1 1106.6c-.7 3-1.1 5.7-.8 6 .2.2.9-2.1 1.6-5.2.7-3 1.1-5.7.8-6-.2-.2-.9 2.1-1.6 5.2zM478.1 1109.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM479.1 1113.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM169.1 1115.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM480.1 1117.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM168.1 1119.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM481.1 1121.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM167.1 1123.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM482.2 1125.5c0 1.1.4 3.1.8 4.5.6 2 .8 2.1.8.5 0-1.1-.4-3.1-.8-4.5-.6-2-.8-2.1-.8-.5zM166.2 1128c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM165.1 1132.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM484.2 1135c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM164.2 1137c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM485.1 1139.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM163.1 1141.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM162.2 1146.5c0 1.6.2 2.2.5 1.2.2-.9.2-2.3 0-3-.3-.6-.5.1-.5 1.8z"/></svg>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankkh/fht8pk71/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two problems.

1. Set the level of the liquid in the bottle. You can do that with a linearGradient setting the stops at the right offset.
2. Animate that fill and for that you can animate the stops with SMIL.

Press enter once you've put in the value you want to see the bottle fill.

```js
function process(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
                Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("animatedStop")).forEach((animation) => {
            animation.setAttribute("to", ele.value + "%");
            animation.beginElement();
 
        });

    }
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <label>Enter Value</label>
  <input min="0" max="100" value="50" id="fill-color" type="textbox" name="fillcolor" onkeydown="process(this)" />%
  <script>
  </script>
</div>
<svg id="octocat" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="450" viewBox="0 0 640 1280">
   <defs>
     <linearGradient id="gradient" x2="0%" y1="100%" y2="0%">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green"/>
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green">
          <animate class="animatedStop" attributeName="offset" to="0%" dur="3s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"/>
       </stop>
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black">
          <animate class="animatedStop"attributeName="offset" to="0%" dur="3s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"/>  
       </stop>
     </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <path id="face" fill="url(#gradient)" d="M289.5 1c-24.5 1.5-44.8 5.2-47.7 8.8-1.5 1.8-1.5 21.6.1 29.7.8 4.1.6 5.5-.9 8.5-2.9 5.7-3.4 11.9-1.5 17.8 2 6 8.8 14.4 11 13.5.8-.3 1.5 0 1.5.6s-.5 1.1-1.2 1.1-.6.6.4 1.7c1.3 1.5 1.7 9.8 2.8 53.8l1.2 52-3.1 18c-7.8 45.2-19.6 83.7-48.4 158.5-11.8 30.7-19.7 53.4-19.7 56.2 0 .7 2.5-5.9 5.4-14.7 3-8.8 11-30.4 17.9-48 16.3-41.8 25.2-67.4 32.3-92.3 1.5-5.1 2.9-9 3.1-8.8 1.6 1.6-16.6 57.4-30.3 92.8-15.6 40.3-16.6 43.1-22.5 60.3-3.2 9.3-5.8 15.9-5.9 14.6 0-1.3-.3-2.1-.7-1.8-.3.4-.9 6.2-1.3 12.9-.6 10.2-1.2 13.4-3.5 18.8-13.7 32-26.5 140.3-22.7 192.1 1 13.7 4 31.1 5.4 31.7 1.5.7.8 4.8-1.2 6.5-1.8 1.5-2 2.9-2 14.4 0 18.6 3.2 44.5 12 98.3 8.2 49.7 11.4 75.5 14.9 117.5 3.7 43.9 4.4 58.5 3.8 83.5-.6 24.9-1.3 31.7-6.3 57.1-1.4 7.2-2.3 13.3-2.1 13.5.2.2 1.2-3.5 2.2-8.3 2.3-11.7 3.3-15.4 3.4-12.8.2 3.7-4.9 28.5-12.9 63-4.4 18.7-8.5 36.4-9.1 39.3-1.5 6.3-2.6 7.5-2.2 2.4.2-3.4.1-3.4-.8.8-1.5 6.9-.5 35.5 1.5 41l1.6 4.5-3.6-3.9-3.7-3.9.7 3.9c2 11.4 6.6 19 16.5 27.3 10.6 8.8 24.3 13.9 49.6 18.6 20.7 3.8 43.3 5.5 81.5 6.2 84.2 1.4 142.2-6.8 171.2-24.3 6.4-3.9 14.1-11.9 15.6-16.3.9-2.5.8-2.8-.8-2.4-1.7.5-1.7.2-.5-3.4.7-2.1 1.6-5.2 1.9-6.8l.7-3-3.5 3.4-3.5 3.3 1.6-4.3c1.1-3.1 1.6-8.6 1.6-18.9.1-14.8-2.1-34.8-3.3-30-.7 2.7-1.1 1.5-4.4-13-1.9-8.1-6.1-25.9-8.6-36.5-3-12.4-7-31.7-6.9-33.5 0-.8.9 1.4 1.9 5 2.6 9.3 2.4 6.3-.5-7.2-5-23.4-5.7-30.3-6.2-59.9-1-56.1 5.3-123.5 19.7-209.9 8.6-51.5 11.9-83.4 10.4-100-.4-4.7-.9-7.7-1.1-6.7-.6 2.2-2.3 1.2-2.3-1.4 0-1.1.4-1.7 1-1.4.6.4.9-1.1.7-3.9-.1-2.4.1-4.3.4-4 3.8 2.3 4.9-76.9 1.6-107.6-3.6-32.7-9-66.4-14.4-89.3-1.7-7.2-2.8-10.5-3.2-9.3-.5 1.3-1.6-.4-3.9-6.4-1.8-4.5-3.2-8.6-3.2-9.3 0-2.3 2 .9 4.4 7.3 1.4 3.6 2.5 5.8 2.5 5 0-.8-1.3-4.7-3-8.5-2.5-5.9-3.2-9.1-3.9-19.6-1.2-15.2-3.3-22.8-14.2-51.3-28.2-73.9-35.7-95.5-43.3-125.1-4.3-16.6-11.1-48.5-13.5-63.5-.7-4.1-1.6-8-2.1-8.6-1.7-2.1-3.1-36.2-2.7-66.3l.4-30.6 2.7-5c1.5-2.8 4.4-6.1 6.5-7.5 8-5.4 11.9-21.9 7.3-31.4-1.5-3.1-2.1-5.8-1.9-8.8l.4-4.3.8 5.3c1.5 9 2.8 4.4 3.4-11.6.5-14.2.4-15-1.6-17-2.5-2.5-6.9-3.8-19.8-5.7-21.9-3.2-69-4.3-99.9-2.5zm-47.2 61.1c2.5 3.6 2.6 3.7.6 4.2-1.6.4-1.8.3-.9-.8.7-.8.7-1.5.1-1.9-.5-.3-1.2 0-1.5.6-.3.7-.3.2 0-1.1.4-1.6.3-2.1-.5-1.7-.7.5-1.1-.1-1.1-1.5 0-1.2.1-2 .3-1.8.2.2 1.5 2 3 4zM405 72.3c0 .2-1 1.2-2.2 2.3l-2.3 1.9 1.9-2.3c1.8-2.1 2.6-2.7 2.6-1.9zM425.8 315c3.8 10.7 12.1 32.8 18.5 49 13.2 34 17.9 46.9 17.4 48.3-.2.6-1.1-1.2-2.1-3.9s-7.5-19.5-14.3-37.4c-15.5-40.2-27.3-73.1-27.3-75.9 0-1.5 1.5 2.4 7.8 19.9zM184 448.8c0 .4-1.7 5-3.9 10.2-2.1 5.2-4.4 11.9-5.1 14.7-.8 2.9-1.7 5.3-2.1 5.3-1 0 3.1-14.9 6.6-23.9 1.5-3.9 3.1-7.1 3.6-7.1s.9.4.9.8zm-17.3 69.4c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm317 5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-318 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm319 6.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm-320 2.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm311 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-302 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm312 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-322 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm10 6c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-314 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm305 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-315 1.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 2.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm316 2.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-9-.5c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-317 4c-.2 1.3-.4.5-.4-1.7-.1-2.2.1-3.2.4-2.3.2 1 .2 2.8 0 4zm327 4.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-318 1c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm309 .5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-319 7.5c-.2 1.6-.4.3-.4-2.7s.2-4.3.4-2.8c.2 1.6.2 4 0 5.5zm9 0c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm311 0c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 3c-.2 1.6-.4.5-.4-2.2 0-2.8.2-4 .4-2.8.2 1.3.2 3.5 0 5zM159 612.5l-.7 38-.1-27c-.2-22.8.6-50.2 1.3-49.3.1.2-.1 17.4-.5 38.3zm331.7-18.8c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-9-10c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-313 2.5c-.2 1.3-.4.5-.4-1.7-.1-2.2.1-3.2.4-2.3.2 1 .2 2.8 0 4zm314 12c-.2 1.8-.4.6-.4-2.7 0-3.3.2-4.8.4-3.3s.2 4.2 0 6zm-315 1.5c-.2 1.6-.4.3-.4-2.7s.2-4.3.4-2.8c.2 1.6.2 4 0 5.5zm324 29c-.1 4.9-.3.9-.3-8.7s.2-13.6.3-8.8c.2 4.9.2 12.7 0 17.5zm-325 7.5c-.1 4-.3.8-.3-7.2s.2-11.2.3-7.3c.2 4 .2 10.6 0 14.5zm324 16.5c-.2 2.1-.4.4-.4-3.7 0-4.1.2-5.8.4-3.8.2 2.1.2 5.5 0 7.5zm-331 4.5c-.2 1.3-.4.3-.4-2.2s.2-3.5.4-2.3c.2 1.3.2 3.3 0 4.5zm8 1.5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm315 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm7 .5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-329 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm8 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 0c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-315.4 2.5c-.7.2-2.1.2-3 0-1-.3-.4-.5 1.2-.5 1.7 0 2.4.2 1.8.5zm311.4 16.5c-.2 1.3-.4.3-.4-2.2s.2-3.5.4-2.3c.2 1.3.2 3.3 0 4.5zm-305 0c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm316 17.5c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-328-8c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm9 3c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm311 12c-.2 3.2-.3.8-.3-5.2 0-6.1.1-8.7.3-5.8.2 2.9.2 7.8 0 11zm-319 8c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm8 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm318 1c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-8 5c-.3 1-.5.2-.5-1.7s.2-2.7.5-1.8c.2 1 .2 2.6 0 3.5zm-317 1.5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm8 1.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm316 4.5c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-323 4c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm315 0c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-307 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm314 1c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-321 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm313 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-305 2c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm312 3c-.3.7-.5.2-.5-1.2s.2-1.9.5-1.3c.2.7.2 1.9 0 2.5zm-319 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm311 3c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm7 1c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm-317 2c-.3.8-.6.5-.6-.6-.1-1.1.2-1.7.5-1.3.3.3.4 1.2.1 1.9zm320 406.5c-.3 1-.5.4-.5-1.2 0-1.7.2-2.4.5-1.8.2.7.2 2.1 0 3zm4.3 46.3c0 .5-1.9 3.3-4.2 6.1-12 14.6-42.4 24.4-94 30.5-17.9 2.1-103.1 3.1-126.7 1.4-19.7-1.3-36-3.3-49.5-6.1-10.2-2.1-29.1-7.7-28.4-8.5.3-.2 3 .5 6.2 1.6 27.2 9.3 81 14 145.1 12.5 43.2-.9 74.1-4.4 100.1-11 23.4-6 37-12.7 45.4-22.3 4.4-5 6-6.1 6-4.2z"/><path d="M159.1 681.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM178.6 1074.6c-.4 2-.5 3.8-.3 4 .3.3.8-1.1 1.1-3.2.4-2 .5-3.8.3-4-.3-.3-.8 1.1-1.1 3.2zM470.1 1074.6c-.2 1.8 3.2 16 3.5 14.9.2-.6-.5-4.4-1.5-8.5s-1.9-7-2-6.4zM177.1 1081.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM175.1 1089.6c-.7 3-1.1 5.7-.8 6 .2.2.9-2.1 1.6-5.2.7-3 1.1-5.7.8-6-.2-.2-.9 2.1-1.6 5.2zM474.1 1092c0 .8.8 4.6 1.8 8.5 1.1 3.8 1.9 6.3 2 5.5 0-.8-.8-4.7-1.8-8.5-1.1-3.9-1.9-6.3-2-5.5zM173.1 1098.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM171.1 1106.6c-.7 3-1.1 5.7-.8 6 .2.2.9-2.1 1.6-5.2.7-3 1.1-5.7.8-6-.2-.2-.9 2.1-1.6 5.2zM478.1 1109.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM479.1 1113.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM169.1 1115.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM480.1 1117.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM168.1 1119.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM481.1 1121.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM167.1 1123.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM482.2 1125.5c0 1.1.4 3.1.8 4.5.6 2 .8 2.1.8.5 0-1.1-.4-3.1-.8-4.5-.6-2-.8-2.1-.8-.5zM166.2 1128c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM165.1 1132.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM484.2 1135c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM164.2 1137c0 1.4.2 1.9.5 1.2.2-.6.2-1.8 0-2.5-.3-.6-.5-.1-.5 1.3zM485.1 1139.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM163.1 1141.6c0 1.1.3 1.4.6.6.3-.7.2-1.6-.1-1.9-.3-.4-.6.2-.5 1.3zM162.2 1146.5c0 1.6.2 2.2.5 1.2.2-.9.2-2.3 0-3-.3-.6-.5.1-.5 1.8z"/></svg>
```

Comment: The code is not taking up textbox value and filling the bottle

Comment: For an exact percentage fill of a shape, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873157/scaling-the-filling-portion-of-an-svg-path

Comment: @MayankKapahi try Firefox. I guess the browser you're using has some bug.

Comment: Yeah, it is not working in chrome @RobertLongson