How to Display and Fill SVG Countries Based on Percentage in iOS (UIKit)
I'm working on an iOS project where I need to display an SVG map of a continent or country, and dynamically fill each region based on a given percentage, similar to a choropleth map. Here's an example of what I'm aiming for with a map of the UK:
SVG image of UK
I've experimented with SVGKit and SwiftSVG to load and display the SVG, but I'm struggling to fill the regions with a color that reflects the percentage (like the red color on the image).
Does anyone know how i could achieve it, or know a better approach/alternative solution for achieving the same result without using SVG? I'm open to any library recommendations or different techniques suitable for iOS development.

I did a brute force solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873157/scaling-the-filling-portion-of-an-svg-path

Off-topic because it's not about programming and it's asking for a tool recommendations. Check [help/on-topic].

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman Nice thank you, the problem is that  in the future the application is suppose to handle the whole world XD But if i have no choice, i will do it like you !

Most of the SVG libraries create a CAShapeLayer for each element in the SVG file.
So, if we use a simple "UK Regions" SVG map that looks like this:

and change the fill color of each region to make it easier to see what's going on:

a library such as SVGKit will generate layers like this:

So, if we want to "fill a region by percentage" we need to manipulate the layer(s).
One approach would be to duplicate the target layer and then mask it by the desired percentage:

Here we're "filling" by 50% ...


Nice thank you so much for this answer, I was on another project that's why i took a long time to see it. But it's pretty clear !
